Three functional tests in`test_runner.py` fail with `JSONRPCException: Method not found (-32601)`
I'm building bitcoind on MacOS 14.7.1 and running the functional test test_runner.py. bitcoind was built minimally with:
cmake -B build \
    -DBUILD_GUI=OFF \
    -DWITH_BDB=OFF  \
    -DBUILD_BENCH=OFF  \
    -DBUILD_FOR_FUZZING=OFF \
    -DBUILD_KERNEL_LIB=OFF \
    -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF \
    -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF \
    -DBUILD_TX=OFF \
    -DBUILD_UTIL=OFF \
    -DBUILD_WALLET_TOOL=OFF

The codebase was prepared for the Chaincode Labs BOSS-2025 program, cloned from v28.0. The build completes without errors. However when running the functional tests from test_runner.py, three of the tests fail: mempool_persist.py, interface_bitcoin_cli.py and feature_rbf.py. All three tests fail with a similar error:
2024-12-03T11:09:18.858000Z TestFramework (ERROR): JSONRPC error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/maestrovt/workspace/github.com/chaincode/bitcoin-core-test-the-test-maestrovt/bitcoin/test/functional/test_framework/test_framework.py", line 132, in main
    self.run_test()
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
  File "/Users/maestrovt/workspace/github.com/chaincode/bitcoin-core-test-the-test-maestrovt/bitcoin/build/test/functional/feature_rbf.py", line 76, in run_test
    self.test_rpc()
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
  File "/Users/maestrovt/workspace/github.com/chaincode/bitcoin-core-test-the-test-maestrovt/bitcoin/build/test/functional/feature_rbf.py", line 622, in test_rpc
    self.init_wallet(node=0)
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/maestrovt/workspace/github.com/chaincode/bitcoin-core-test-the-test-maestrovt/bitcoin/test/functional/test_framework/test_framework.py", line 444, in init_wallet
    n.createwallet(wallet_name=wallet_name, descriptors=self.options.descriptors, load_on_startup=True)
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/maestrovt/workspace/github.com/chaincode/bitcoin-core-test-the-test-maestrovt/bitcoin/test/functional/test_framework/test_node.py", line 936, in createwallet
    return self.__getattr__('createwallet')(wallet_name, disable_private_keys, blank, passphrase, avoid_reuse, descriptors, load_on_startup, external_signer)
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/maestrovt/workspace/github.com/chaincode/bitcoin-core-test-the-test-maestrovt/bitcoin/test/functional/test_framework/coverage.py", line 50, in __call__
    return_val = self.auth_service_proxy_instance.__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/maestrovt/workspace/github.com/chaincode/bitcoin-core-test-the-test-maestrovt/bitcoin/test/functional/test_framework/authproxy.py", line 146, in __call__
    raise JSONRPCException(response['error'], status)
test_framework.authproxy.JSONRPCException: Method not found (-32601)
2024-12-03T11:09:18.918000Z TestFramework (INFO): Stopping nodes
2024-12-03T11:09:19.327000Z TestFramework (WARNING): Not cleaning up dir /var/folders/zh/y9jqq2qd6v5brxd0vdx6_rxh0000gq/T/test_runner_₿__20241203_060247/feature_rbf_125
2024-12-03T11:09:19.327000Z TestFramework (ERROR): Test failed. Test logging available at /var/folders/zh/y9jqq2qd6v5brxd0vdx6_rxh0000gq/T/test_runner_₿__20241203_060247/feature_rbf_125/test_framework.log
2024-12-03T11:09:19.328000Z TestFramework (ERROR): 
2024-12-03T11:09:19.365000Z TestFramework (ERROR): Hint: Call /Users/maestrovt/workspace/github.com/chaincode/bitcoin-core-test-the-test-maestrovt/bitcoin/test/functional/combine_logs.py '/var/folders/zh/y9jqq2qd6v5brxd0vdx6_rxh0000gq/T/test_runner_₿__20241203_060247/feature_rbf_125' to consolidate all logs
2024-12-03T11:09:19.365000Z TestFramework (ERROR): 
2024-12-03T11:09:19.386000Z TestFramework (ERROR): If this failure happened unexpectedly or intermittently, please file a bug and provide a link or upload of the combined log.
2024-12-03T11:09:19.386000Z TestFramework (ERROR): https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues
2024-12-03T11:09:19.386000Z TestFramework (ERROR): 

I'm a newbie to building and testing bitcoind, any suggestions appreciated!
After doing some searching I discovered that the problem was with my build configuration and specifically that wallet functionality was not enabled. When I rebuilt with the following cmake flags and ran the tests, all passed fine:
maestrovt@Edwards-MacBook-Pro bitcoin % cmake -B build \
    -DWITH_SQLITE=ON \          # Enable SQLite for descriptor wallets
    -DWITH_BDB=OFF \            # Disable Berkeley DB (legacy wallets not needed)
    -DBUILD_WALLET_TOOL=ON \    # Include wallet tool
    -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF \
    -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF

